# Muenchian Grouping, Sorting & Filtering using XSLT version 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping, biztalk

I have an XML which is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnterpriseDocument ClientID="1000101" CreationTimestamp="2013-12-20T00:03:40.740" InterfaceName="InterfaceExport" ClientName="Zomba" CreationSource="Base" Version="1.0">
  <BusinessUnitList>
    <BusinessUnit buName="Site 1" buCode="0001" countryCode="TD">
      <FuelItemList>
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000001" fuelItemName="Fuel_1" fuelItemExtID="1" price="1.0001" priceType="Liquid" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-19" startTime="10:15" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000001" fuelItemName="Fuel_1" fuelItemExtID="1" price="1.0001" priceType="Liquid" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-16" startTime="12:58" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0001" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="10:15" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0001" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-19" startTime="16:20" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0001" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="10:15" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0001" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-19" startTime="16:20" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000004" fuelItemName="Fuel_4" fuelItemExtID="4" price="4.0001" priceType="LiquidNitrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-19" startTime="23:58" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000004" fuelItemName="Fuel_4" fuelItemExtID="4" price="4.0001" priceType="LiquidNitrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-18" startTime="13:58" />
      </FuelItemList>
    </BusinessUnit>
    <BusinessUnit buName="Site 2" buCode="0002" countryCode="GK">
      <FuelItemList>        
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000001" fuelItemName="Fuel_1" fuelItemExtID="1" price="1.0001" priceType="Liquid" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-19" startTime="12:15" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0001" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="18:20" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000004" fuelItemName="Fuel_4" fuelItemExtID="4" price="4.0001" priceType="LiquidNitrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-19" startTime="22:58" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0001" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="12:15" />       
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000001" fuelItemName="Fuel_1" fuelItemExtID="1" price="1.0001" priceType="Liquid" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-16" startTime="17:58" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0001" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="18:20" />       
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0001" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="12:15" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000004" fuelItemName="Fuel_4" fuelItemExtID="4" price="4.0001" priceType="LiquidNitrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-18" startTime="15:58" />
      </FuelItemList>
    </BusinessUnit> 
  </BusinessUnitList>
</EnterpriseDocument>
```

I need to get an output as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnterpriseDocument ClientID="1000101" CreationTimestamp="2013-12-20T00:03:40.740" InterfaceName="InterfaceExport" ClientName="Zomba" CreationSource="Base" Version="1.0">
  <BusinessUnitList>
    <BusinessUnit buName="Site 1" buCode="0001" countryCode="TD">
      <FuelItemList>
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0001" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="10:15" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0001" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="10:15" />    
      </FuelItemList>     
    </BusinessUnit> 
    <BusinessUnit buName="Site 2" buCode="0002" countryCode="GK">
      <FuelItemList>
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0001" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="12:15" />       
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0001" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="12:15" />
      </FuelItemList>
    </BusinessUnit>
    <BusinessUnit buName="Site 2" buCode="0002" countryCode="GK">
      <FuelItemList>
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0001" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="18:20" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0001" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="18:20" />
      </FuelItemList>
    </BusinessUnit>
    <BusinessUnit buName="Site 1" buCode="0001" countryCode="TD">
      <FuelItemList>        
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0001" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-19" startTime="16:20" />       
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0001" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-19" startTime="16:20" />        
      </FuelItemList>     
    </BusinessUnit> 
  </BusinessUnitList>
</EnterpriseDocument>
```

The rules that must be applied to attain the above are as follows:

1. The output must contain only Fuel Items with fuelItemExtID= 2 or 3. [Filtering]
2. The output must be sorted as per the startDate and startTime for every Fuel Item within a Business Unit. [Sorting in ascending order, latest on top]
3. The output must be grouped as per the unique value of startDate and startTime combination. [Grouping based on concat(@startDate, '+', @startTime]

NOTE: I need solution only in XSLT 1.0 version.

Please let me know, if you need any clarification.

My Attempt is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
        xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var"
        exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />

    <xsl:key name="GroupByStartDateTime" match="//FuelItem" use="concat(@startDate, '+', @startTime)" />

    <xsl:template match="/" >
        <EnterpriseDocument InterfaceName="{//@InterfaceName}" Version="{//@Version}" CreationTimestamp="{//@CreationTimestamp}" CreationSource="{//@CreationSource}" ClientID="{//@ClientID}" ClientName="{//@ClientName}" >
            <BusinessUnitList>
                <xsl:for-each select="//BusinessUnit">
                    <xsl:variable name="businessUnit" select="."/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$businessUnit/FuelItemList/FuelItem">
                        <xsl:sort select="@startDate" />
                        <xsl:sort select="@startTime" />
                        <xsl:variable name="fuelItem" select="."/>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$fuelItem[generate-id() = generate-id(key('GroupByStartDateTime',concat(@startDate, '+', @startTime)))]">
                            <xsl:if test="@fuelItemExtID=2 or @fuelItemExtID=3">
                                <BusinessUnit buCode="{../../@buCode}" buName="{../../@buName}" countryCode="{../../@countryCode}" >
                                    <FuelItemList>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('GroupByStartDateTime',concat(@startDate, '+', @startTime))" mode="Item" />
                                    </FuelItemList>
                                </BusinessUnit>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </BusinessUnitList>
        </EnterpriseDocument>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="FuelItem" mode="Item">
        <FuelItem
          fuelItemID="{@fuelItemID}"
          fuelItemExtID="{@fuelItemExtID}"
          fuelItemName="{@fuelItemName}"
          price="{@price}"
          startDate="{@startDate}"
          startTime="{@startTime}"
          priceType="{@priceType}"
          serviceType="{@serviceType}"
            />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is as below:

```
<EnterpriseDocument InterfaceName="InterfaceExport" Version="1.0" CreationTimestamp="2013-12-20T00:03:40.740" CreationSource="Base" ClientID="1000101" ClientName="Zomba">
    <BusinessUnitList>
        <BusinessUnit buCode="0001" buName="Site 1" countryCode="TD">
            <FuelItemList>
                <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemExtID="2" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" price="2.0001" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="10:15" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" />
                <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemExtID="3" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" price="3.0001" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="10:15" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" />
            </FuelItemList>
        </BusinessUnit>
        <BusinessUnit buCode="0001" buName="Site 1" countryCode="TD">
            <FuelItemList>
                <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemExtID="2" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" price="2.0001" startDate="2013-12-19" startTime="16:20" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" />
                <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemExtID="3" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" price="3.0001" startDate="2013-12-19" startTime="16:20" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" />
            </FuelItemList>
        </BusinessUnit>
        <BusinessUnit buCode="0002" buName="Site 2" countryCode="GK">
            <FuelItemList>
                <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemExtID="2" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" price="2.0001" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="12:15" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" />
                <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemExtID="3" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" price="3.0001" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="12:15" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" />
            </FuelItemList>
        </BusinessUnit>
        <BusinessUnit buCode="0002" buName="Site 2" countryCode="GK">
            <FuelItemList>
                <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemExtID="3" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" price="3.0001" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="18:20" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" />
                <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemExtID="2" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" price="2.0001" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="18:20" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" />
            </FuelItemList>
        </BusinessUnit>
    </BusinessUnitList>
</EnterpriseDocument>
```

Comment: Where is the example of your attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: My apologies for initially not sharing my attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing: your Muenchian groupings are not set up correctly: you need to select items that are **first** in their group. Instead of:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//BusinessUnit[generate-id() = generate-id(key('GroupByBusinessUnit',@buCode))]">
```

you should have:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//BusinessUnit[generate-id() = generate-id(key('GroupByBusinessUnit', @buCode)[1])]">
```

Other than that, it seems to me that this could be simplified to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method='xml' version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' indent='yes'/>

<xsl:key name="similarItems" match="FuelItem[@fuelItemExtID=2 or @fuelItemExtID=3]" use="concat(../../@buCode, '+', @startDate, '+', @startTime)" />

<xsl:template match="/EnterpriseDocument">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <BusinessUnitList>
        <xsl:for-each select="//FuelItem[generate-id() = generate-id(key('similarItems', concat(../../@buCode,  '+', @startDate, '+', @startTime))[1])]">
        <xsl:sort select="@startDate" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:sort select="@startTime" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            <BusinessUnit>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../../@*"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('similarItems', concat(../../@buCode, '+', @startDate, '+', @startTime))">
                <xsl:sort select="@fuelItemExtID" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </BusinessUnit>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </BusinessUnitList>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your original input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnterpriseDocument ClientID="1000101" CreationTimestamp="2013-12-20T00:03:40.740" InterfaceName="InterfaceExport" ClientName="Zomba" CreationSource="Base" Version="1.0">
  <BusinessUnitList>
    <BusinessUnit buName="Site 1" buCode="0001" countryCode="TD">
      <FuelItemList>
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000001" fuelItemName="Fuel_1" fuelItemExtID="1" price="1.0001" priceType="Liquid" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-19" startTime="10:15" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000001" fuelItemName="Fuel_1" fuelItemExtID="1" price="1.0001" priceType="Liquid" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-16" startTime="12:58" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0001" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="10:15" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0001" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-19" startTime="16:20" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0001" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="10:15" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0001" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-19" startTime="16:20" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000004" fuelItemName="Fuel_4" fuelItemExtID="4" price="4.0001" priceType="LiquidNitrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-19" startTime="23:58" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000004" fuelItemName="Fuel_4" fuelItemExtID="4" price="4.0001" priceType="LiquidNitrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-18" startTime="13:58" />
      </FuelItemList>
    </BusinessUnit>
    <BusinessUnit buName="Site 2" buCode="0002" countryCode="GK">
      <FuelItemList>        
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000001" fuelItemName="Fuel_1" fuelItemExtID="1" price="1.0001" priceType="Liquid" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-19" startTime="12:15" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0001" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="18:20" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000004" fuelItemName="Fuel_4" fuelItemExtID="4" price="4.0001" priceType="LiquidNitrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-19" startTime="22:58" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0001" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="12:15" />       
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000001" fuelItemName="Fuel_1" fuelItemExtID="1" price="1.0001" priceType="Liquid" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-16" startTime="17:58" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0001" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="18:20" />       
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0001" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="12:15" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000004" fuelItemName="Fuel_4" fuelItemExtID="4" price="4.0001" priceType="LiquidNitrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-18" startTime="15:58" />
      </FuelItemList>
    </BusinessUnit> 
  </BusinessUnitList>
</EnterpriseDocument>
```

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnterpriseDocument ClientID="1000101" CreationTimestamp="2013-12-20T00:03:40.740" InterfaceName="InterfaceExport" ClientName="Zomba" CreationSource="Base" Version="1.0">
  <BusinessUnitList>
    <BusinessUnit buName="Site 1" buCode="0001" countryCode="TD">
      <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0001" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="10:15"/>
      <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0001" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="10:15"/>
    </BusinessUnit>
    <BusinessUnit buName="Site 2" buCode="0002" countryCode="GK">
      <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0001" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="12:15"/>
      <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0001" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="12:15"/>
    </BusinessUnit>
    <BusinessUnit buName="Site 2" buCode="0002" countryCode="GK">
      <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0001" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="18:20"/>
      <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0001" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-08-17" startTime="18:20"/>
    </BusinessUnit>
    <BusinessUnit buName="Site 1" buCode="0001" countryCode="TD">
      <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0001" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-19" startTime="16:20"/>
      <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0001" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2013-12-19" startTime="16:20"/>
    </BusinessUnit>
  </BusinessUnitList>
</EnterpriseDocument>
```

Using your alternative input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnterpriseDocument ClientID="1000001" CreationTimestamp="2014-01-10T13:56:47.259" InterfaceName="InterfaceExport" ClientName="Zomba" CreationSource="Base" Version="1.0">
  <BusinessUnitList>
    <BusinessUnit buName="Site 1" buCode="0001" countryCode="TD">
      <FuelItemList>
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000001" fuelItemName="Fuel_1" fuelItemExtID="1" price="1.0050" priceType="Liquid" serviceType="Great" startDate="2014-01-10" startTime="13:45" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000001" fuelItemName="Fuel_1" fuelItemExtID="1" price="1.0100" priceType="Liquid" serviceType="Great" startDate="2014-01-10" startTime="13:46" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0050" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2014-01-10" startTime="13:45" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0100" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2014-01-10" startTime="13:46" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0050" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2014-01-10" startTime="13:45" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0100" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2014-01-10" startTime="13:46" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000004" fuelItemName="Fuel_4" fuelItemExtID="4" price="4.0050" priceType="LiquidNitrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2014-01-10" startTime="13:45" />
        <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000004" fuelItemName="Fuel_4" fuelItemExtID="4" price="4.0100" priceType="LiquidNitrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2014-01-10" startTime="13:46" />
      </FuelItemList>
    </BusinessUnit>
  </BusinessUnitList>
</EnterpriseDocument>
```

The result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnterpriseDocument ClientID="1000001" CreationTimestamp="2014-01-10T13:56:47.259" InterfaceName="InterfaceExport" ClientName="Zomba" CreationSource="Base" Version="1.0">
  <BusinessUnitList>
    <BusinessUnit buName="Site 1" buCode="0001" countryCode="TD">
      <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0050" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2014-01-10" startTime="13:45"/>
      <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0050" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2014-01-10" startTime="13:45"/>
    </BusinessUnit>
    <BusinessUnit buName="Site 1" buCode="0001" countryCode="TD">
      <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000002" fuelItemName="Fuel_2" fuelItemExtID="2" price="2.0100" priceType="LiquidSynthetic" serviceType="Great" startDate="2014-01-10" startTime="13:46"/>
      <FuelItem fuelItemID="0000003" fuelItemName="Fuel_3" fuelItemExtID="3" price="3.0100" priceType="LiquidHydrogen" serviceType="Great" startDate="2014-01-10" startTime="13:46"/>
    </BusinessUnit>
  </BusinessUnitList>
</EnterpriseDocument>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, there is a problem with the code you have shared. Firstly, the attributes of Enterprise Document are not appearing in the output. I can add that, not a problem. Secondly, the script fails for a particular case. Check the input file below.

Comment: @user3205378 I believe I have fixed both issues now.

Comment: Wonderful, works flawlessly. Request you to explain, what was the issue in the case of alternate input file.

Comment: @user3205378 The issue was that the key matched fuel items of *all* types; thus the fuel item that was first in its group (by BusinessUnit+startDate+startTime) was not necessarily of type 2 or 3. If the answer works for you, please close this question by accepting it.

Comment: Since am new to this forum, I am not sure how to close. Can you please guide me on this. I have clicked on the tick mark and accepted it as answer. Do I need to do anything else.

Comment: @Gov Thank you, that's all you needed to do. Please note that I have now removed the `[@fuelItemExtID=2 or @fuelItemExtID=3]` predicate from the `xsl:for-each` call; it is no longer necessary since a similar predicate has been added to the key.

Comment: Thanks. Change noted.